# Getting illegal start of expression as error

Tags: java, runtime-error

Im trying to run the program again, and now i'm getting this error.

here is my code:

```
public static void writeBirdtype() {

private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
  StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader();
   new FileReader(filePath);
   char[] buf = new char[1024];
   int numRead=0;

    while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
        String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
        fileData.append(readData);
    }
    reader.close();
    return fileData.toString();
    }
```

error:

```
Oblig2.java:72: error: illegal start of expression
private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
^
Oblig2.java:72: error: ';' expected
private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
                               ^
Oblig2.java:72: error: ';' expected
private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
                                               ^
Oblig2.java:72: error: not a statement
private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
                                                        ^
Oblig2.java:72: error: ';' expected
private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
                                                                   ^
5 errors
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks alot for help

Comment: I placed the code outside `writeBirdtype`, but now this error shows up: no suitable constructor found for BufferedReader(). Do you have any clue why it says that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest methods in Java.  Place the code for the `readFileAsString` method outside the code for the `writeBirdtype` method.

Also, these 2 lines don't make sense and will generate a compiler error:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader();
new FileReader(filePath);
```

The first is a compiler error, because there is no zero-argument constructor for [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#constructor_summary).  And, then you construct a new `FileReader` and ignore it.

It looks like you mean this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
```

Comment: I placed the method outside now, but now this error shows up: no suitable constructor found for BufferedReader(). Do you have any clue why it says that?

Comment: I have added additional explanation to my answer.